# PHP time period "7 days, 18:50:19"

Tags: php, time, period

What is the best way to convert this time period to seconds in php?
"7 days, 18:50:19" ~> "67000"

Comment: How did you arrive at the value `7 days, 18:50:19`

Comment: Why 67,000? A single day has 86,400 seconds already. Did you lose one order of magnitude here …?

Comment: oh sorry one 0 is missing, should be 670000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) can parse a "period" format like that natively, the only key point is to also pass in `0` as the second parameter so that the result is relative to the unix epoch rather than the current time:

```
$seconds = strtotime('7 days 18:50:19', 0);
echo $seconds;
```

> 672619

Answer (score -1):

Can we do better then this?

```
$interval = "7 days, 18:50:19";
$interval = preg_replace("/[a-z A-Z]/", "", $interval);
$int = preg_split( "/(,|:)/", $interval);
$inter = ($int[0]*86400) + ($int[1]*3600) + ($int[2]*60) + ($int[3]);
var_dump($inter);
```